# ubuntu 13.04: user name

Tags: 13.04

Nautilus (the file manager) shows Home > Dropbox
but Dropbox shows Home > User > Dropbox

What is going one? Is it a display issue or has the file tree been altered?

I haven't used Terminal commands in so long I have forgotten how to figure it out at that level - but after upgrading to 13.04 yesterday Dropbox stopped updating, almost certainly because Dropbox thinks these files are at Home > User > Dropbox but the system seems to have eliminated the User level. Show hidden files doesn't help.

I can't use Ubuntu without Dropbox, and it has worked for 5 years, now I am flummoxed.

Comment: Nautilus just calls `/home/[user]` as **Home**. Note the capitalization. Dropbox folder should be in `/home/[user]/Dropbox`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons its not working:

1. http_proxy is set
2. https_proxy is set
3. dropboxd is not being called correctly

In the command line do the following:

```
unset http_proxy https_proxy
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Does the dropbox icon show up in the toolbar?  If so is the menu blank? If YES/NO then you should be fine.

I don't know what the webproxy is all about...